# REGEX : Splitting String into Fixed Length w/o Breaking Words AND Including Specials

Tags: java, regex

I have the following REGEX...

```
\S.{1,40}\b\W?
```

This will break a string into smaller strings no longer than 40 characters long and will not break up the words (plus includes punctuation). However what it won't handle is special characters such as # on their own IF it ends up at the end of the string (less than 40 characters long.) I assume because the regex doesn't see it as a word?

Take the following example...

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno (# #)
```

The result will be...

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno
```

Where the result should be the same as the input (including the (# #) at the end).

Take this example as well...

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno (# #)
blah blah etc etc words and more words and yet more words. What about these words?
And some more text for this string so that we can test things out.
```

In this case the results should be...

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno (# #)
blah blah etc etc words and more words 
and yet more words. What about these 
words?
And some more text for this string so 
that we can test things out.
```

However again, with my current regex above the results are...

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno 
blah blah etc etc words and more words 
and yet more words. What about these 
words?
And some more text for this string so 
that we can test things out.
```

Notice that the (# #) is missing. I need this (# #) to be included in the first result.

Please note I'm using this regex in Java using Pattern and Matcher classes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you might want to pre- or post-process your first-like sentences, otherwise the expression would become rather complicated, then maybe the following expression would be somewhat close:

```
.{0,39}\S(?=$|\s)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VjqquA/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VjqquA/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/B5lwhC/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Emma for the very quick reply. Unfortunately this doesn't get me what I'm looking for. But I can see why as I wasn't fully clear that I needed to be able to do this with a larger string as well. Let me modify my question to add more detail...

Comment: BTW, your java example is pretty much what I'm using to do this. Except in my while (matcher.find()) loop I'm simple adding matcher.group to an ArrayList. So I have the list of strings as a result and return them from my method.

Comment: You're amazing! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! Only change I had to make was to just trim() the results to get rid of redundant whitespace on either end of the result.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried `\S.{1,40}\b\W?` will also match 41 or 42 chars because the `\S` will match 1 non whitespace character followed by matching matching any char 1- 40 times. After that you can also optionally match a non word char like for example `#`

What you might do is keep the same start of the pattern but match 0-39 chars and change the condition of the boundary at the end using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

You could assert that what is on the left is a non whitespace char and what is on the right is not a non whitespace char to not match any spaces at the end.

```
\S.{0,39}(?<=\S)(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\S` Match a non whitespace character
- `.{0,39}` Match any char 0 -39 times
- `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is a non whitespace char
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wRAHZc/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Jtztlt)

For example

```
String regex = "\\S.{0,39}(?<=\\S)(?!\\S)";
String string = "abcd (efghij # / klmno (# #)\n"
     + "blah blah etc etc words and more words and yet more words. What about these words?\n"
     + "And some more text for this string so that we can test things out. ";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Result

```
abcd (efghij # / klmno (# #)
blah blah etc etc words and more words
and yet more words. What about these
words?
And some more text for this string so
that we can test things out.
```